# Web api have different response in different environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

When I call service using the browser, or postman [image: Postman] response is true, which is ok. But if a call this service using a code I have different result [image]

Is the way not identical?

**Here is code on angular side**

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authentificateUser(email, password) {
    return this.http.get('/api/LogIn/Authentification?email=' + email + '&password=' + password).source;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public bool Authentification(string email, string password)
{
    var user = new SystemUser();
    if (user.EmailAddress == email && user.Password == password)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I use ASP.NET core

Answer (score 0):

What does http.get().source do ?

Have you tried using Observables?

```
    authentificateUser(email, password) : Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get<any>('/api/LogIn/Authentification?email=' + email + '&password=' + password, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

Comment: result is the same :/

Comment: Can you subscribe to the response in your component that is calling `authentificateUser(em, pwd)` ?

`authentificateUser(email, password) : Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
     this.http.get<any>('/api/LogIn/Authentification?email=' + email + '&password=' + password).subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data) }));
  }`

Answer (score 0):

In the new `HttpClient` JSON is assumed as a default response. That's why you see the Object in the console.

If you want to Request non-JSON data you need to tell it explicitly using `responseType` option.
**ModifiedCode:**

```
 return this.http.get('/api/LogIn/Authentification?email=' + email + '&password=' +
 password,{responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: Hi if the provided answer or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this:)